# ES6 Destructuring in Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn Destructuring in Javascript introduced with ES6.
While following a medium post I came across this code :

```
function displaySummary({ name, scores: { maths = 0, english = 0, science = 0 } }) {
    console.log('Hello, ' + name);
    console.log('Your Maths score is ' + maths);
    console.log('Your English score is ' + english);
    console.log('Your Science score is ' + science);
}
```

I know this is a way of Destructuring but how do i pass arguments while calling this function?
I have tried calling it like

```
displaySummary({'John Doe',{1,2,3}});
```

But got an error something like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ','`

How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level of the parameter list has no commas, so you need to pass a single argument, which has the structure of:

```
{ name, scores: { maths = 0, english = 0, science = 0 } }
```

except with `:`s instead of `=`s. So:

```js
function displaySummary({ name, scores: { maths = 0, english = 0, science = 0 } }) {
    console.log('Hello, ' + name);
    console.log('Your Maths score is ' + maths);
    console.log('Your English score is ' + english);
    console.log('Your Science score is ' + science);
}


displaySummary({ name: 'bob', scores: { maths: 95 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument of the function `displaySummary` is not a valid `Object`

```
displaySummary({'John Doe',{1,2,3}});
```

the function definition expect to receive an object which has this shape

```
{ 
    name: "John Doe", 
    scores: { 
        maths = 0, 
        english = 0, 
        science = 0 
    } 
}
```

But in your call you pass an object which has no keys